# Parsing using the ArduinoJson library

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to parse JSON using the ArduinoJson library. The problem is that I can’t parse www.read() because it’s declared as a char. I think www.read() needs to be a string? How can I convert www.read() into a format that jsonBufffer.parseObject() can understand? Please excuse any lack of terminology. I am new to using JSON.

When I run the code I get to the point where it prints "-------------------------------------” then it does nothing.

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// These are the interrupt and control pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
// These can be any two pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10
// Use hardware SPI for the remaining pins
// On an UNO, SCK = 13, MISO = 12, and MOSI = 11
Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS,   
ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER); // you can change this clock speed

#define WLAN_SSID       "WLAN_SSID_HERE" // cannot be longer than 32    characters!
#define WLAN_PASS       "WLAN_PASS_HERE"
// Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2

#define IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS  300000      // Amount of time to wait (in milliseconds) with no data 
// received before closing the connection.  If you know the server
// you're accessing is quick to respond, you can reduce this value.

// What page to grab!
#define WEBSITE      "wefeel.csiro.au"
#define WEBPAGE      "/api/emotions/primary/totals"


StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;



uint32_t ip;

void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("Hello, CC3000!\n")); 

  /* Initialise the module */
  Serial.println(F("\nInitializing..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    Serial.println(F("Couldn't begin()! Check your wiring?"));
    while(1);
  }


  Serial.print(F("\nAttempting to connect to ")); 
  Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);
   if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  Serial.println(F("Request DHCP"));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }  

  /* Display the IP address DNS, Gateway, etc. */
//  while (! displayConnectionDetails()) {
 //    delay(1000);
//  }

  ip = 0;
  // Try looking up the website's IP address
  Serial.print(WEBSITE); 
  Serial.print(F(" -> "));
  while (ip == 0) {
    if (! cc3000.getHostByName(WEBSITE, &ip)) {
      Serial.println(F("Couldn't resolve!"));
    }
    delay(500);
   }

  cc3000.printIPdotsRev(ip);

}

void loop(void)
{
  char c;
  Adafruit_CC3000_Client www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);
  delay(300);
  if (www.connected()) {
    www.fastrprint(F("GET "));
    www.fastrprint(WEBPAGE);
    www.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Host: ")); 
    www.fastrprint(WEBSITE); 
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.println();
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));    
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));

  unsigned long lastRead = millis();
  while (www.connected() && (millis() - lastRead < IDLE_TIMEOUT_MS)) {
    //Serial.print(www.available());
    while (www.available()) {
  
  
      //Serial.print(c);
      //char json[] = www.read();
    }
  } 
  c = www.read();
  Serial.print(c);
 JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject((char*)c);
 if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
    return;
    }

  long love = root["love"];
  long other = root["other"];
  long sadness = root["sadness"];
  long anger = root["anger"];
  long joy = root["joy"];
  long surprise = root["surprise"];
  long fear = root["fear"];

  Serial.println(love);
  Serial.println(other);
  Serial.println(sadness);
  Serial.println(anger);
  Serial.println(joy);
  Serial.println(surprise);
  Serial.println(fear);


  www.stop();
  delay(100);
  www.close();
  delay(200);
 }
```

Comment: First you never setup the HTTP header with "Content-Type: application/json", so the data return might not be in json as you want. Secondly, you need to create a buffer to store the response back from the server within the `while(www.available()) { buffer[i++]=www.read(); }` (i.e. read the data char by char and store in the buffer), then you can parse the return data in the buffer with `JsonObject& root=jsonBuffer.parseObject(buffer);`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `read` methods. One that returns a single character (or error), and one that populates a buffer; you want the latter, with method signature `int read(char* buf, size_t len)` or some such. Read the source.

When allocating the json buffer in `StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;`
, make sure your expected json data fit in 200 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my problem. I'm assuming you would use  `jsonBuffer` as `uint8_t *buf` but what value do I use for `size_t len`?

Comment: no, `jsonBuffer` has to still be a `StaticJsonBuffer`. It's what you `read()` into that should change. Something along the lines of:

    char buf[256];
    size_t n_read = www.read(buf, 255);
    buf[n_read] = '\0';

You need the third line because `parseObject` expects a nul-terminated string.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think Im following you but am still unclear what I need to do next. Im thinking it is calling `jsonBuffer.ParseObject` but I was thinking that I would have it parse `n_read` which seems to be incorrect? What variable should I perform the parse on?